# How to write firestore security rules to allow only read and write on your data with no subcollections?

Tags: database, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having trouble writing firestore security rules. I have a "users" collection where the documents are logged in users. The users are created when a user signs up via google sign-in using firebase auth. The auth ID is not stored as the document ID, but in a field called "user_id" in each document in the "users" collection. I have another collection called "table_values" where the document contains a set of fields, one of them being "user_id". This "user_id" field is the associated with the "user_id" field in the user_collection.

I want to make it so that only the table_values who's "user_id" field matches the "user_id" field for the user who is currently logged in are displayed. How should I write my security rule to accomplish this?

The answers I've seen have sub-collections associated with each user, which I don't have, or have the auth id as the user document id, which I also don't have. I was wondering how I can write security rules with my current data structuring.

[image: user collection]

[image]

Comment: Try using [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) method to compare fields. Example: `match /table_values/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.user_id == resource.data.user_id;
}`.

Comment: You cant do that. You will have to use the `user_id` as the document name in your `table_values` and `users` collections. How come you "don't have" this value?